# Изображение из временного хранилища

Tags: javascript, изображения, typescript, axios, xmlhttprequest

С сервера приходит изображение `content-type: image/jpeg`, в запросе приходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как это выглядит в развернутом `response.data`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом картинку видно в DevTools
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно вывести это изображение в тэг `<img />`, а в лучшем случае записать как `File` или `Blop`

Я пробовал найти ответы но ничего дельно не нашёл :(

Comment: responceType: arraybuffer

Comment: похоже что Вы показали headers, которые Вы шлете при запросе.
Что у Вас с responce headers ?

Comment: @GayratVlasov нет, на первой картинке axios.response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов загрузить картинку как `blob` объект и создать url объект с помощью `URL.createObjectURL`, далее url объект передать в `img.src`.

**Axios**

```
axios.get(url, {
  responseType: 'blob'
})
.then((response) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
});
```

---

**Fetch**

```
fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.blob())
.then((response) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(response);
});
```